# Indexing problem 2 different sites on same server. One site breaks other

Tags: magento2, indexer

We are facing a problem with indexing.

There are two magento 2 installations, (diferent hosting, different domains, running different fpm pools with different users , different and independant databases with different users and restricted access to its own databases).

When we run a user1# `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`, the **category-product indexes** of the other site is emptied. (and viceversa) other indexes like search,... seems fine...

Did someone have a hint of where to look at?

Comment: Have you check magento log files?

Comment: Nothings shows up on log, no error no info.

Comment: Which mode the website is running?

Comment: tried prod dev, one prod one dev, mixing all combinations